# How to Retrieve Video and Audio Streams from an RTMP Server, Process, and Transmit to Another RTMP Server?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming

I'm currently working on a project that involves extracting both video and audio streams from an RTMP server, performing some real-time processing on them, and then forwarding the processed streams to another RTMP server.

I'm able to extract the video stream, process it and transmit it but I have yet to find how to do the same with the audio.

Here is the current implementation I have:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(INPUT_URL)

# command and params for ffmpeg
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', f"{width}x{height}",
           '-r', str(fps),
           '-i', '-',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-preset', 'ultrafast',
           '-f', 'flv',
           OUTPUT_URL]

# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("frame read failed")
        break

    # CODE FOR PROCESSING FRAME HERE

    # write to pipe
    p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
```

I tried using PyAudio but I'm unable to get the audio from the server. Is there possibly a way to get both the frames and the audio with FFmpeg?

Any advice or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: opencv is the wrong library for this.